# Oracle sql to split data into ranges based on count

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a requirement where I need to populate a table with range based on the records count from input
Sample O/p if the input has 8954 records :- The # of records from input will keep changing, where as the split based on 3K records is constant.

```
Entity start end
abc    1     3000
abc    3001  6000
abc    6001  8954
```

I have tried using hierarchical query but it fails after 1 million records due to memory issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please always state your precise Oracle version every time you ask a question. Oracle keeps adding new and more powerful things to SQL; you don't want a solution that works for us but not for you ;)

Comment: You should show the query that fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use hierarchy query to generate the records as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      'abc' AS ENTITY,
  3      ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 3000 + 1 as st,
  4      LEAST(LEVEL * 3000, 8954) as en
  5  FROM
  6      DUAL
  7  CONNECT BY
  8      LEVEL <= CEIL(8954 / 3000);

ENT         ST         EN
--- ---------- ----------
abc          1       3000
abc       3001       6000
abc       6001       8954

SQL>
```

replace 8954 with actual value in above query.